# how to use iterators to replace a block of repeating integers with a preceding string

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I'm struggling with the below list trying to replace every block of 0s with a preceding character. I'd like a regex- or using itertools module solution.

```
ss1=['k', 0, 0, 0, 'z', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'c','p', 0, 0]
```

The list I'm working with contains a few thousand items.
The desired output: `[k,k,k,k,z,z,z,z,z,c,p,p,p...]`
Many thanks!

I was just curious how it is done via regex or itertools. Nothing is wrong with using a for loop and a variable to remember the last preceding non-0 value.

Comment: What do you mean with *iterators-based* solution: lazy evaluation, or list comprehension?

Comment: using itertools module

Comment: What is wrong to use a for loop and a variable to remember the last preceding non-0 value?

Comment: @JingshaoChen: well it's rather pythonic (and functional programming) to use all kind of building blocks like `map`, `fold`, `filter`, etc. Functional programming aims to minimize the amount of code since some programmers assume the more lines you write the more things can go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) for this:

```
result = itertools.accumulate(ss1,lambda x,y: x if y == 0 else y)
```

The code works as follows: `accumulate` takes a list `[p0,p1,p2,...,pn]` and always emits first `p0`, so we are fine with that one.

Next it calls the function `f` (here `lambda x,y: x if y == 0 else y`) with `p0` and `p1`. In our function we check if `p1` is `0`, if that is the case, we return `p0` and otherwise we take the new value (and return `p1`).

Now in the next iteration, `accumulate` calls again `f`, but now with the *result of the previous iteration* and `p2`, and so we have a scanline algorithm that keeps emitting the previous item, until no zero is fed as second argument.

If I run this in python:

```
>>> result = itertools.accumulate(ss1,lambda x,y: x if y == 0 else y)
>>> list(result)
['k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'c', 'p', 'p', 'p']
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's also possible using `itertools` but a simple generator could be used as well:

```
def replace_following_zeros(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    item = next(it)
    yield item
    while True:
        item2 = next(it)
        if item2 != 0:
            item = item2
        yield item

>>> list(replace_following_zeros(ss1))
['k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'c', 'p', 'p', 'p']
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could use itertools, a fairly simple generator approach would also work:

```
>>> def fill(seq):
...     last_el = None
...     for el in seq:
...         if isinstance(el, str):
...             last_el = el if last_el != el else last_el
...         yield last_el if last_el else el
... 
>>> L = ['k', 0, 0, 0, 'z', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'c', 'p', 0, 0]
>>> list(fill(L))
['k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'c', 'p', 'p', 'p']
>>>
```

Comment: Aren't you overrestricting yourself: who says `str` objects will be feeded: the specifications only say something about zero. Furthermore the approach is not that dynamic since a minor change in the specs could result in a different method.

Comment: I  don't think so. He said he wanted to convert each chunk of integers to the last known _character_. He said character, so I that is what my code is testing for; a "character".

Comment: where do you read that? The only literal the OP mentions is `0`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem _"I'm struggling with the below list **trying to replace every block of 0s with a preceding character**"_?

Comment: yeah my point is that it is in case `1` is feeded, the specs are not very clear.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry for confusing specs. Both ways are useful to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @leaf sorry for confusing specs. Both ways are useful to me. Thanks a lot!